# Criteria API Path to sub-sub-entity id

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want to transform my JPAQL queries into criteria API queries.

Consider query like this:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.parent.id = :parentId
```

`WHERE` part is transformed to:

```
Path<Long> parentId = root.get(Entity_.parent).get(ParentEntity_.id);
Predicate whereParentId = builder.equal(parentId, selectedParent.getId());
```

The question is, how to create predicate for WHERE like this:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.parent.parent.id = :parentId
```

How to create `Path` to parent of parent id?

Answer (score 8):

If the JPQL you've shown is working, then I'll assume that your `ParentEntity` is holding a reference to its parent (in a form of `parent` field of `ParentEntity` type). Therefore, something like this should work:

```
Path<Long> parentId = root.get(Entity_.parent)
    .get(ParentEntity_.parent)
    .get(ParentEntity_.id);
Predicate whereParentId = builder.equal(
    parentId, selectedParent.getId()
);
```

I've done similar thing but for one entity (`Customer` is child and parent entity at the same time and references its parent through `parent` field of `Customer` type) and something like this worked perfectly fine:

```
query.select(customer)
     .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(
         customer.get("parent").get("parent").get("id"), 
         criteriaBuilder.parameter(int.class, "parentId"))
     );

List<Customer> customers = em.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter("parentId", john.getId()).getResultList();
```

Comment: How would yo do it for an element inside a Map?

`Path path = entity.get("mapAtribute)...`

I don't know how to pass the Key once I get the Map to get the desired Element.

Here it is my hole question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436972/jpa-2-criteria-for-sorting-based-on-an-atribute-from-a-map-value

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e inner join e.parent p WHERE p.id = :parentId
```

in  criteria call it an Alias like:

```
sess.createCriteria(Entity.class)
    .createAlias("e.parent", "p")
```